# Creating an animation illustrating the time-evolution of a pre-computed orbit

Tags: plotting, graphics, animation

As the title says, I would like to use Mathematica in order to create an animation depicting the time-evolution of a three-dimensional (3D) orbit. To begin with, I have an ASCII file which contains the orbit data into four columns. The first column corresponds to the time, while the next three to the x, y and z coordinates respectively. Below, I present a simple code so as to visualize the orbit.

```
SetDirectory[" ... "];
data = ReadList["orb_3d.out", Number, RecordLists -> True];
dataOrb3D = Table[{data[[i, 2]], data[[i, 3]], data[[i, 4]]}, 
{i, 1, Length[data]}]; 
S0 = Graphics3D[Line[dataOrb3D], Axes -> True, AxesStyle ->
Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], AxesLabel -> 
{"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

The above code produces this image:

[image]

In order to obtain the ASCII data file, please follow [this link](http://www.mediafire.com/?vjtt48hi2af7eso).

OK, so far so good. Now let me explain the simulation part. The orbit describes the motion of a test-particle (star) under the gravitational field of a galaxy. According to the data file, when t=0 the star must be at (x,y,z) = (0.5,0,0.5). So, I would like to plot at that point, let's say a blue dot, inside the 3D volume. Then as time evolves the blue dot which indicates the star should follow the path according to the data file moving from point to point, join them thus leaving a solid line behind it. When t=250 the simulation finishes and we should have reproduced the image I present earlier.

Honestly, I am not sure if what I described is possible with Mathematica. Anyway, it would be great, if there was also a label inside the 3D box (or above it) giving the value of the time at every step of the simulation (i.e. t = 73.27). Finally, I would also like to be able to export this simulation as an .avi or .mp4 file.

I know that I described a very ambitious project here! However, I also think that it is a very interesting topic. Many many thanks in advance and I look forward for your replies.

Comment: By the way, this is not really *simulation*; this is just *animation*. Simulation would be if you gave us only the inverse square law and the initial state of the particle, and asked us to plot its orbit.

Comment: @RahulNarain YES! You are absolutely right; it is just an animation. The simulation or if you prefer the numerical integration of the equations so motion was made using a FORTRAN algorithm. The output was the ASCII data file.

Comment: Why not perform the numerical integration in Mathematica as well? `NDSolve` is amply able to deal with equations of motion.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Indeed, Mathematica could also perform the numerical integration of the equations of motion. However, my experience shows that the corresponding FORTRAN code is always much faster. Moreover, if you want to integrate for vast time intervals using Mathematica you may run out of memory! I could post such an example.

Comment: fortran is probably faster, indeed, but your experience also told you that this would be an ambitious project whereas it's actually trivial in mathematica! my point is that mathematica can be made to do things that surprise most people (on the other hand, it's debatable whether the effort necessary to learn enough to do that is worth it)

Comment: @acl I absolutely agree. A mere line of Mathematica (NDSolve, FindRoot, for example) means dozens and dozens of FORTRAN sentences.

Comment: What I meant is a bit different: a few months ago I needed to numerically integrate a large number (5000) of coupled nonlinear ODEs; I did this in Mathematica and it was perfectly doable. It would probably have been faster in C, but so what?. On the other hand, also recently, we implemented a symplectic integrator in mathematica (which presumably is what you're also using for this). We had to rewrite it in C to get over license number limitations and it was indeed faster, about 50 times.

Comment: So my point is, it's probably not as big a difference as you think. On the other hand if one's comfortable with Fortran, there's nothing to be gained by spending time learning all the tricks necessary to get Mathematica fast enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A few important things:

- Fix `PlotRange` so the axes won't rescale constantly - otherwise you will have no sense of the orbit scale as it progresses
- Set `SphericalRegion -> True` for a nice feel of box rotation
- Want animation not to get stuck while you are rotating the box? - wrap `Dynamic` around the internal content of `Graphics3D`
- Note the `AnimationRate` option for setting speed of the orbit progress

Here you go:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
data = ReadList["orb_3d.out", Number, RecordLists -> True];
space = data[[All, 2 ;; 4]];

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[Dynamic@{
    {GrayLevel[.7], Line[space[[1 ;; t]]]},
    {Red, PointSize[.02], Point[space[[t]]]},
    },
  Axes -> True, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> 10, SphericalRegion -> True],
 Row[{Control[{t, 1, Length[data], 1, Animator, ImageSize -> Small, 
     AnimationRunning -> False, AnimationRate -> 50,AnimationRepetitions -> 1}], Spacer[10], 
   Dynamic["time = " <> ToString[data[[t, 1]]]]}],
 FrameMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

To export to movie

```
Export["test.avi", %]
```

To export without interface - replace `Manipulate` with `Table` and then export the resulting list of graphics to .GIF or .AVI. or similar. See related documentation for flexible options - like looped or single run - for .GIF it is "AnimationRepetitions".

Comment: Great, simply amazing! Only, a couple of minor issues left now. 
(1). How can I change the properties of the moving point (size, color, etc)?
(2). Is there a way to display the exact time somewhere during the simulation?
(3). When the simulation ends I want the image to freeze not starting again.
(4). Is it possible to export the simulation as an .avi or mp4. file?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z please state whatever you need from the very beginning in your question - don't have too much time to go changing code. (1) all options are in the code - examine attentively; (2) I displayed time now; (3) exported movie to .AVI or .GIF will stop if you set propper options. You can find a lot of useful info reading help - just search in documentation for AVI, GIF, Manipulate, or Dynamic

Comment: Thanks a lot! One minor issue is left. At the end of the animation (t=250), I would like the animation to freeze there not restarting all over again. Is this possible?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Yes, this is "AnimationRepetitions -> 1" option - I added it to the code.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z As with most options, "AnimationRepetitions" is well documented: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Animate.html#878404649

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I would like to thank you for your illuminating instructions!

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Is it possible to include the time indicator "t = ###" somewhere inside the 3D volume or just above it but not as it is now; at the end of the line with all the buttons.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Yes, consider "PlotLabel" option for `Graphics` or even better `Epilog` - see [**2nd example here**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Epilog.html).

Answer (score 14):

Here is one that uses the `Tube` primitive, where the front of the tube is a little
thicker than the tail. It also uses a non-stationary `ViewPoint` which creates the 
illusion of flying around the animation and zooming in and out of it. The `DisplayAllSteps`
option makes sure than Animate does not skip any intermediate steps:

```
points = Import["Downloads/orb_3d.out", "Table"][[All, 2 ;; 4]];

length = Length[points];
step = 10;
tubeLength = 200;

Animate[
 Graphics3D[{
  {Blue, Sphere[]}, 
  Tube[points[[i ;; i + tubeLength]], 
   Table[i/(4 tubeLength), {i, 1, tubeLength + 1}]
 ]}, 
 PlotRange -> 30, 
 Background -> Black, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 ViewPoint -> (6 + 5 Cos[i/500]) {Cos[i/1000.], Sin[i/1000.], Sin[i/2000]},       
 SphericalRegion -> True
], {i, 1, length - tubeLength, 10}, DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

[image: Star around black hole animation]

Comment: +1 The tube is a great idea for giving a 3D visual cue.

Answer (score 10):

## Minimal modifications

It's almost trivial to do this with minor modifications to your code:

```
data = ReadList["orb_3d.out.txt", 
   Number, RecordLists -> True];

Manipulate[
 dataOrb3D = 
  Table[{data[[i, 2]], data[[i, 3]], data[[i, 4]]}, {i, 1, uplim}];
 Graphics3D[
  {Line[dataOrb3D], Sphere[data[[uplim, 2 ;; -1 ]], .5 ]},
  Axes -> True,
  AxesStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 500,
  PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}
  ],
 {uplim, 1, Length@data, 1}
 ]
```

(I just moved `dataOrb3D` inside a `Manipulate`, fixed the plot range, and inserted a sphere at the end of the line).

## Slightly tidier code

I'd prefer it like this though (no extra `Table` at the beginning):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  {Line[data[[1 ;; uplim, 2 ;; -1]] ],
   Sphere[data[[uplim, 2 ;; -1 ]], .5 ]},
  Axes -> True,
  AxesStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 500,
  PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}
  ],
 {uplim, 1, Length@data, 1}
 ]
```

## The Earth

Embellishments are also possible. For instance, let's add a tiny Earth:

```
pl = Import[
  "http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/57000/57752/land_\
shallow_topo_2048.tif"];

earth = SphericalPlot3D[1 , {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
   Mesh -> None,
  ImageSize -> 100,
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, 1 - #4} &), 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 10], Texture[pl]], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  Axes -> False,
  RotationAction -> "Clip",
  Boxed -> False
  ]

Manipulate[
 Show[
  {
   Graphics3D[
    {Pink, Line[data[[1 ;; uplim, 2 ;; -1]] ]},
    Axes -> True,
    AxesStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
     AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 500,
    PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}
    ],
   Graphics3D[Scale[Translate[earth[[1]], data[[uplim, 2 ;; -1]]], 2]]
   },
  Lighting -> "Neutral"
  ],
 {uplim, 1, Length@data, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

A couple of comments.

Note the use of `earth[[1]]` in `Graphics3D[Translate[earth[[1]], data[[uplim, 2 ;; -1]]]]`; this is necessary to extract the `GraphicsComplex`, otherwise `Translate` doesn't work. It's a shame we can't use `Texture` with primitives like `Sphere`.

Exporting to a gif is easy; replace the `Manipulate` by a `Table`, then export the resulting list as `Export[fname,list]`.

Comment: Many many thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It's fairly easy to export to an animation.  Here's one way to export the first tenth of it to an animated GIF.  Other formats can be done by simply changing the extension.

```
$Path = Prepend[$Path,
   FileNameJoin[{HomeDirectory[], "Downloads"}]];
data = Import["orb_3d.out", "Table"];
positions = Rest /@ data;
pic[n_] := Graphics3D[{
    {Opacity[0.2], Line[positions]},
    {Line[positions[[1 ;; n]]],
     PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[positions[[n]]]}
    }];
pics = Table[pic[n], {n, 1, 2501, 25}];
Export["anim.gif", pics];
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to thank you for your illuminating instructions!