# Show a gif of polynomial equations' roots

Tags: graphics, polynomials, animation

I want to show the solutions of polynomial equations $P_n(x)=y$.

For example, let $P_5(x)=x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+1=y\ ,\;y\in[-10,10]$,

```
sol[i_,j_]:=Join[#,{i}]&/@ReIm[x/.NSolve[x^5+x^4+x^3+x+1==i+j I]];
p=Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.25],InfinitePlane[{{0,0,1},{1,0,1},{1,0,0}}]}];
gifs=Table[Show[
    ListPointPlot3D[Flatten[Table[sol[i,0],{i,-10,10,0.1}],1],
    BoxRatios->{1,1,1},AxesOrigin->{0,0,0},Boxed->False,
    ViewPoint->{2Sin[t],2Cos[t],1.5}],p],
    {t,0,2Pi,0.1}];
Export["poly5.gif",gifs, "AnimationRepetitions"->Infinity]
```

[image]

Oh...terrible, the image is constantly shaking, at least the origin point should be fixed.

Secound, I want to get the curves instead of points, $n$ curves when $P_n(x)$. I can only get points if I use `NSolve`.

Then I can dye according to their distance from the plane, I mean real plane XoY, the distance equal to imaginary part.

And if the curve on that plane, use special colour like red. If the curve just cross the plane, also highlight that point red.

Comment: What happens if you add the option `SphericalRegion -> True`?

Comment: Related/duplicates: [(16765)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16765), [(85304)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85304), [(157271)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/157271)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another piece of the puzzle, specifically how to get continuous lines instead of points by using `Solve` and `ParametricPlot3D`.

```
p = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.25], InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}]}];
sol = Solve[x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 == y, x]
(* five Root solutions *)
Show[p,
  ParametricPlot3D[Append[ReIm[x], y] /. sol, {y, -10, 10}], 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Animated:

[image: Animated]

EDIT:

GalAster points out that this approach has a problem with another polynomial `x^4 + x^3 - 2 x - 1`.

```
sol = Solve[x^4 + x^3 - 2 x - 1 == y, x, Quartics -> False]
(* four Root solutions *)
Show[p,
  ParametricPlot3D[Append[ReIm[x], y] /. sol, {y, -10, 10}], 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True,
  , AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im", "y"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Indeed, this has some spurious connectors when the bifurcation occurs and the roots change order.  Evidently a well-placed `Evaluate` fixes this problem.

```
Show[p,
  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Append[ReIm[x], y] /. sol], {y, -10, 10}, MaxRecursion -> 12],
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im", "y"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow, `Root` can be used like this! A small commit, `Solve[P, x, Quartics -> False, Cubics -> True]` or something terrible would happen on some cases.

Comment: Well, not solved, still have problem, try `x^4 + x^3 - 2 x - 1`

Answer (score 4):

This answers the shaking part. As  @Michael E2 said, if you add `SphericalRegion -> True` the shaking goes away

This animation with `SphericalRegion -> True`

[image]

This is without

[image]